# Actual Role of SharedPrefrences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-room

If we're saving user data in a local DB through Room Lib, and then we login as a valid user, we're successfully showing his name in dashboard activity. Then how do SharedPrefrences play their role?

Comment: They play no role on the scenario you described

Comment: In your example they don't.  SharedPreferences provides persistent key-value storage without having to create a full db.  For some things that's useful.  For others, not.  For that case, there's no use unless you want to persist some side data (say the login token).

Answer (score 0):

The introduction in the Android developer guide answers your question very well.

> Android provides several options for you to save your app data. The
>   solution you choose depends on your specific needs, such as how much
>   space your data requires, what kind of data you need to store, and
>   whether the data should be private to your app or accessible to other
>   apps and the user.

(See: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage)

Sometimes you just need to store a single value (e.g. a number or a string). In this case the SharedPrefrences API provides you a simple method to read and write the value.